# Intellij Navigate > Class... exclude certain files

Tags: android, android-studio, workflow

When I use `Navigate` > `Class...` or <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> (on OSX) and I enter the classname I want to open, there are many generated class I don't want to see (like `*$$ViewBinder.java` or `*$$IcePick.java`).

How can I hide all generated (NOT DECOMPILED) classes from there?

**[edit]**

A screenshot as wished in the comments:
[image]

Comment: dont see that happening on windows. can you share a screenshot of how it looks like at your end

Comment: I cant see any generated classes in the screenshot. They are all from the framework or referenced libraries. This is expected.

Comment: All the gray classes i.e. starting with `MapModule_` are in `build/generated`. They are generated, aren't they?

Comment: doubt it, they are regular classes with underscore in the library

Comment: ah, you mean generated that way. That's right. There generated means decompiled. Its actually something people want most of the time to see what the framework or a library class looks like. Not sure how to filter those out sorry.

Comment: btw, you could use "Search everywhere" by hitting Shift twice. There you will see only project classes. (Generated ones stil show but are highlighted in yellow, so you know they are generated). Also posting this as an answer

Comment: Do you see diferences when you press `SHIFT`+`CMD`+`O`?

Comment: nope, still the same

Comment: Your IDE behaviour is different than mine. I only see generated classes when i type `SHIFT`+`CMD`+`O`.

Comment: what I use to hide the generated files when I navigate, instead of searching for "map" I use "src/map"

Answer (score 1):

Try marking the directory as Excluded.

```
Right click -> Mark Directory As -> Excluded.
```

The **link** is for **clion** but it should work.
https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2015/12/mark-dir-as/

Comment: doesnt work as I cant mark anything in the build folder